# How to prevent partials in main layout from being re-rendered/updated on every page request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, render, partials

Having looked around for hours, reading blogs and many other SO questions with no success, I finally got to ask for help.

I believe I still lack some understanding about the Rails layout/render/yield mechanisms.
Therefore this maybe a stupid question. I beg your pardon.

Is it possible to prevent partials from being rendered on every page request? I mean, every time I click a link on my app the layouts and partials are reloaded.

My goal is to have a somehow static side bar, populate it once by rendering the partial "the first time application.html.erb is loaded", and then update it using ajax only.

Here is my app layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "GEN" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "GEN" %>">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body class="darkbody">
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <nav class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
      <div class="container-fluid">

         <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span3">

            <%= render partial: 'charts/dashboard', layout: false %>

          </div>

          <div class="span9">
            <div class="well well-small">
              <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>

              <%= yield %>  

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

The "dashboard" partial should load once and never be rendered again.
In other words, navigating the app would change/refresh content in the yield section but not in the main layout "partials".

The motivation? The dashboard uses a helper method to show a value that is computed and never updated throughout the user session. If I get many reloads this helper runs on every user click and stresses the app server even if returning the same result, what happens indeed.

Is this too crazy or stupid?

Best regards,

AD

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it will render HTML from this template on each request, but if data which is displayed in template doesn't need to be actual all the time, you can try action or fragment caching, like this:

```
  <div class="span3">
    <% cache 'dashboard' do %>
      <%= render partial: 'charts/dashboard', layout: false %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

You can read more details in rails guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching)

Comment: Very nice, @Ivan K. Is there any tips for testing in dev mode?
I wrapped my "render" statements in cache blocks wo/ success.

Should I use the full path in the cache param?

Comment: Back and forth, I am starting to believe the cache wont help. I have a helper function inside the partial that crawls the database...

I should find another way of doing that, and move to a SPA in near future. Full ajax will do the trick, imho.